# Line chart start at Feb not Jan

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

My line chart, which is posted below via a jsfiddle starts from February and I would like to see it to start from January. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/TXPWK/66/

Comment: please provide non-minified version of your code next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently using this:

```
new Date(2012,h+1)
```

Remove the +1 and it starts from January